# Dynamic memory management for a class hierarchy of geometric shapes

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management, inheritance

The task was to write function that compare areas of two random generated geometric shapes (circle, square, rectangle) using base class with virtual function.

Am I doing it right in terms of memory management?
Will my figures generated inside generateRandomShape() by new Square() etc. last in memory outside this function untill I manually delete them?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>

#define M_PI       3.14159265358979323846

class Shape {
public:
    virtual float area() = 0;
};

class Square : public Shape {
protected:
    float sideA;

public:
    Square(float sideA) : sideA(sideA) {}
    float area() { return sideA * sideA; }
};

class Circle : public Shape {
protected:
    float radius;

public:
    Circle(float radius) : radius(radius) {}
    float area() { return M_PI * radius * radius; }
};

class Rectangle : public Shape {
protected:
    float sideA, sideB;

public:
    Rectangle(float sideA, float sideB) : sideA(sideA), sideB(sideB) {}
    float area() { return sideA * sideB; }
};

void compareAreasOffigures(Shape* a, Shape* b){
    if (a->area() == b->area()) {
        std::cout << "Areas of two shapes are equal." << std::endl;
    }
    else if (a->area() > b->area()) {
        std::cout << "Area of first Shape is bigger." << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Area of second Shape is bigger." << std::endl;
    }
}

Shape * generateRandomShape() {
    int Shape;
    Shape = rand() % 3;

    switch (Shape)  {

        case 0: {
            int sideA = rand() % 100;
            std::cout << "Square was generated, side: " << sideA << std::endl;
            return new Square(sideA);
            break;
        }

        case 1: {
            int sideA = rand() % 100;
            int sideB = rand() % 100;
            std::cout << "Rectangle was generated, side A: " << sideA << " side B: " << sideB << std::endl;
            return new Rectangle(sideA, sideB);
            break;
        }
        case 2: {
            float radius = rand() % 100;
            std::cout << "Circle was generated, radius: " << radius << std::endl;
            return new Circle(radius);
            break;
        }
        default: return NULL;
    }
}

int main(void){

    srand(time(0));

    std::vector<Shape*> shapes;

    shapes.push_back(generateRandomShape());
    shapes.push_back(generateRandomShape());

    compareAreasOffigures(shapes[0], shapes[1]);

    for (auto v : shapes) { delete v; } //cleanup
    shapes.clear();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Dynamic Memory Management

> Am I doing it right in terms of memory menagment?

You should rather use [smart pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) to store the `Shape` instances in the vector:

```
 std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Shape>> shapes;
```

and

```
 std::unique_ptr<Shape> generateRandomShape() {
     int Shape; // Take care! Some compilers don't like it if variables 
                // arenamed the same as defined types
     Shape = rand() % 3;

         switch (Shape)  {
         case 0: {
             int sideA = rand() % 100;
             std::cout << "Square was generated, side: " << sideA << std::endl;
             return std::make_unique<Square>(sideA);                 
         } break; // Put the break out side the case scope block
         case 1: {
             int sideA = rand() % 100;
             int sideB = rand() % 100;
             std::cout << "Rectangle was generated, side A: " << sideA << " side B: " << sideB << std::endl;
             return std::make_unique<Rectangle>(sideA, sideB);
         } break;
         // ...
     }
     // No need for the default case
     return std::unique_ptr<Shape>();
}
```

thus you can completetly omit

```
 for (auto v : shapes) { delete v; } //cleanup
```

> Will my figures generated inside generateRandomShape() by new Square() etc. last in memory outside this function untill I manually delete them?

Yes, but handling `new` and `delete` on your own turns out to be error prone and semantically unclear.

### Use `virtual` destructors for dynamic polymorphic inheritance

For formal correctness you should declare `virtual` destructors for your abstract base class and the derived classes

```
class Shape {
public:
    float area() = 0;
    virtual ~Shape() = default; // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
};
```

This isn't done automatically for compiler generated destructors (see an explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7041958/1413395)).

### Use `const` class members whenever appropriate

Use `const` whenever appropriate. The `area()` calculation doesn't change any of the internal states of a `Shape` instance, so it should be declared as a `const` member function:

```
class Shape {
public:
    float area() const = 0;
              // ^^^^^ 
};
```

This improves your classes to be used in wider contexts, e.g. with temporary class instances.

Also you could rewrite your function signature

```
void compareAreasOffigures(Shape* a, Shape* b);
```

like that then

1)

```
void compareAreasOffigures(const Shape* a, const Shape* b);
```

or even better

```
void compareAreasOffigures(const Shape& a, const Shape& b);
```

---

**Note:** Do that as soon as possible in your class designs, adding later is much harder than removing that constraint in a later refactoring or *override*.

### Prefer `const` variable definitions over using preprocessor macros

Instead of

```
 #define M_PI       3.14159265358979323846
```

rather use

```
const double M_PI = 3.14159265358979323846;
```

or

```
constexpr double M_PI = 3.14159265358979323846;
```

for sake of type safety and clarity.

### Don't use `srand()`, `rand()` with modern c++

Use a better random number generator than

```
srand(time(0));

// ...

rand();
```

There are various random generators available with the current standard in the [numerics library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random).

### Don't use `==` to compare floating point values

Don't use equality comparison for floating point types like

```
if (a->area() == b->area())
```

it's unlikely these will be exactly equal.

Rather test against [`std::numeric_limits::epsilon`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/epsilon), there's a comprehensive example in the linked documentation.

### Your purpose of using `_USE_MATH_DEFINES` is unclear and inconsistent

Your use of `_USE_MATH_DEFINES` and defining `M_PI` yourself is inconsistent.

The purpose of `#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES` is to use the predefined constants from `cmath` or `math.h`, but you define `M_PI` yourself anyways.

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6563891/1413395) it should be defined *before* any of the `#include` statements to guarantee it works

```
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
```

since you cannot know if any of the other header files already includes `cmath` or `math.h`.

### The highlight of your solution

After so many points of critique, I want to emphasize one **bonus point of your solution**:

You weren't trapped by the *`Square` is not a `Rectangle`* confusion and provided unrelated classes for these (same for *`Circle` is not an `Ellipse`*).

Beginners often use inheritance like

```
class Rectangle {
protected:
    float sideA, sideB;
};

class Square : public Rectangle {
};
```

and run into trouble to keep the class member variables consistent (here's a more detailed [resource](http://cafe.elharo.com/programming/a-square-is-not-a-rectangle/)).

---

1

<sub>As mentioned by [@Tamoghna Chowdhury](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/100478/tamoghna-chowdhury) before.</sub>

Comment: Thank you! :ˆ) IIRC you only need to `virtual ˜Shape() = default` in the base class. The rest will have it implicitly. Doing it at least once is important.

Comment: @Maikel Yes you remembered correctly ;-)

Comment: @Maikel I at least adopted the `default` form. Though its a bit more typing the semantics is clearer.

Comment: Comparing against `epsilon` is [unlikely to be correct](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/02/25/comparing-floating-point-numbers-2012-edition/). You should consider two floating point numbers to be "equal" when they're _close enough_, which depends on what the numbers are used for.

Answer (score 1):

[@πάντα ῥεῖ](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/52802/%cf%80%ce%ac%ce%bd%cf%84%ce%b1-%e1%bf%a5%ce%b5%e1%bf%96)'s answer covers everything except something I think should have been obvious - a square is-a rectangle geometrically. Hence to go by OO design, `Square` should be a subclass of `Rectangle` if both are immutable (to avoid inconsistency among member variables), which they are in this case.

`Square` does not even need any of its own fields or an implementation of the `area()` method that way - via proper initialization in the constructor, the base class `Rectangle`'s relevant fields and methods can handle it.

```
class Square : public Rectangle {
public:
    Square(float side) : Rectangle(side, side) {}
};
```

Note: @πάντα ῥεῖ disagreed with this, quoting [this](http://cafe.elharo.com/programming/a-square-is-not-a-rectangle/) article. I'll bring the last part of the article to your attention to show that this approach is not incorrect for immutable classes:

> As long as the `Rectangle` class is **immutable**, we **can define subclasses** that are **limited** to a **particular subset of rectangles**, such as **squares**. **This is one more reason to prefer immutability**. To the extent possible, define the public interface in terms of what an object is and what it does rather than what you can do to it. However that’s not always possible, and in those cases you need to be extremely careful around inheritance. Otherwise constraints can be violated when you least expect, thus introducing subtle and potentially dangerous bugs in your code.

<sub>Emphasis mine</sub>

As far as I can see, combined with @πάντα ῥεῖ's suggestion for `const` member variables, your `Shape` subclasses are all effectively immutable, and hence my advice follows through. See the explicit absence any properties, setters or public fields - that implies your classes are immutable; and hence, a square is-a rectangle.

Now, if in the future you need to make your `Shape` classes mutable, please do follow @πάντα ῥεῖ's advice and make `Square` an implementation of the highest common interface, `Shape`, instead of a subclass of `Rectangle`. However, as long as they are immutable, this approach is both valid mathematically and OOP-ly (satisfies the Liskov Substitution Principle and the Single Responsibility Principle).

Other tiny nitpicks:

1. Minor typo: `compareAreasOffigures` should be `compareAreasOfFigures` to be consistent *camelCase*.
2. `compareAreasOffigures(Shape* a, Shape* b)` could be `compareAreasOffigures(const Shape& a, const Shape& b)`, using `const` references instead of pointers. Gets you some syntax sugar for free, too.

   The whole method then becomes:

   ```
   void compareAreasOfFigures(const Shape& a, const Shape& b){
       // 5 digits of precision should be enough, go up to 7 if required
       if (almostEqual(a.area(), b.area(), 5)) {
           std::cout << "Areas of two shapes are equal." << std::endl;
       }
       else if (a.area() > b.area()) {
           std::cout << "Area of first Shape is bigger." << std::endl;
       }
       else {
           std::cout << "Area of second Shape is bigger." << std::endl;
       }
   }
   ```

   You'll need this bunch of imports and a template function:

   ```
   #include <limits>
   #include <type_traits>
   #include <algorithm>

   template<class T>
   typename std::enable_if<!std::numeric_limits<T>::is_integer, bool>::type
       almostEqual(T x, T y, int ulp)
   {
       // the machine epsilon has to be scaled to the magnitude of the values used
       // and multiplied by the desired precision in ULPs (units in the last place)
       return std::abs(x-y) < std::numeric_limits<T>::epsilon() * std::abs(x+y) * ulp
       // unless the result is subnormal
              || std::abs(x-y) < std::numeric_limits<T>::min();
   }
   ```

   <sub>Code taken from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/epsilon as was suggested by @πάντα ῥεῖ</sub>

Comment: Oh, you beat me about a minute or so. I added about the same point ;-), and I said exactly the opposite. A `Square` isn't a `Rectangle` from the OOP point of view.

Comment: See here for example: http://cafe.elharo.com/programming/a-square-is-not-a-rectangle/